# Como eu defino uma unidade de medida no valor da variável?

Tags: c, tipagem, sintaxe

Tenho uma questão pedindo que eu calcule o valor do volume de uma lata de óleo, e pensando nisso vou utilizar `float`. Como eu faço para colocar uma  unidade de medida, por exemplo a variável `altura = 50cm`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não faz, é problema da aplicação lidar com esse tipo de coisa, você estabelece qual é a unidade que está manipulando, o código entende unidades de alguma, o que essa coisa só o programador sabe, o código não.

É até possível criar algum mecanismo sofisticado para lidar com isso, mas em C não compensa.

Então guarde 50 em `altura` e tenha consciência que são centímetros.

Comment: show entendi , mas caso seja um código que realmente precise  informar a unidade posso colocar nos comentários né?

Comment: Pode, claro, ou deve.

Comment: Eu costumo usar a unidade no nome da variável, por exemplo algo assim: `altura_em_cm`. Ajuda a não confundir, por exemplo, uma medida de tempo em milissegundos vs. outra relacionada que esteja em segundos.